# SQL: select * from users: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, while using the native query, I am using the following code:

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users');
return $users;
```

But, I am getting the error like the following:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from users)
```

My .env file is this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_seven
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Can you help me here?

Comment: Just type your mysql root password after `DB_PASSWORD=` or setting it to `DB_PASSWORD=null` will probably try it without password.

Comment: @PKeidel I made DB Password to null and it worked great. You have a big brain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment: put your password after `DB_PASSWORD=` or setting it to `DB_PASSWORD=null`

Explanation:

In your posted error the message contains "using password: YES" what means that a password was used. According to your .env there is no password. But laravels `env()` function returns an empty string in that case.

That empty string is used as the password what is not what you want. You have to get `env('DB_PASSWORD')` to return `null` for auth without password.

This can be archived by writing `DB_PASSWORD=null` or removing that line. But writing it out prevents future you and others from thinking that it was forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

How is your database server hosted? Often this error is linked to a non-authorization of the remote root.

For example, this command :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And after, restart your Mysql service

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Can you tell me Where should I put the above command?